# inline vs static for nonmember global variables

Tags: c++, c++17, inline, one-definition-rule

Presume I have a C++ header

> utils.h

And I want to have some constant map available in multiple TUs(map is not inside a class, normal global variable/constant).

```
const std::map<int, std::string> ToString{{1,"1"}, {2, "2"}};
```

Should I declare it inline or static?
In other words:

```
static const std::map<int, std::string> ToString{{1,"1"}, {2, "2"}};
```

or

```
inline const std::map<int, std::string> ToString{{1,"1"}, {2, "2"}};
```

(AFAIK both will work to prevent ODR violation, static by making the linkage internal, and inline by making it ok to have multiple definitions, but I could be wrong, I often make mistakes wrt ODR).

Note: I want to avoid solutions using `extern`.

Comment: Have you considered declaring it with `extern` linkage and defining it in one of the TUs?

Comment: I know for certain that `inline` will work and not cause an ODR violation.  not so sure about `static`

Comment: I do know that going the static route will give each TU a "copy" of the object.  So a change to it in one TU will not be reflected in others.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I hate that solution :), I will modify question to mention that I want to avoid extern.

Comment: @NathanOliver good point, I plan on not modifying it, but true, for mutable map it is difference in behavior(I believe).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with extern linkage. It's a core part of C++. And, as an extra-special bonus it will avoid the need to recompile every TU in order to change values in the map.

Comment: Even if you don't plan on modifying, there isn't really a reason to give each TU its own copy.  All that does is waste resources.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know, I just find it less readable. It is personal preference.

Comment: `static` might also be problematic with ODR if there is `inline` function afterward which refer to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! AFAIK you can use both to achieve your goal:

```
// utils.h

#include <map>

static inline const std::map<int, std::string> ToString{{1,"1"}, {2, "2"}};
```

- `inline` hints to the compiler to consolidate all the files that include this header into a single one, thus meeting the ODR. Note: In C++20, `inline` is just for readability, as the compiler will ignore it if it's not going to improve performance.
- `static` forces `ToString` to be a compile-time value which helps with performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option

```
// header file main.h

#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <string>

static const auto& get_string_map()
{
    static const std::map<int, std::string> ToString{ {1,"1"}, {2, "2"} };
    return ToString;
}

// implementation file main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    auto map = get_string_map();
    std::cout << map.at(1);
}
```

Comment: Now, the question is `static` or `inline` function?

Comment: `auto map` -> `const auto& map` or `auto&& map` to avoid copy.